# Android NiftyDialogEffects library not working with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, github, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I was testing this excelent library, and it works excellent (with the example that comes included).

[NiftyDialogEffects](https://github.com/sd6352051/NiftyDialogEffects)

but when I want to use in my project throws me an error...

My project use the **AppCompat Actionbar** and **Fragments**.

when I run the project I get the following error:

**you need to use a theme.appcompat theme (or descendant)**

How do I make it work?

thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, I had to specify a default theme to the main activity, works fine now.